# Updating GUI while execution a python function while keeping this function GUI-independent

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, auto-update

I have got a python function that takes a few parameters and executes a few tasks (let's call it theFunc). While theFunc runs, internal variable resultingMessage is getting more and more lines, and I show it on GUI at the end of the execution. Ideally, I would like resultingMessage to be shown and updated on GUI as the execution of theFunc happens, not after it has finished, and to do it without polluting theFunc with GUI stuff (it is complicated enough already). What would be the best way to do it?

Two possible ways I could think of (both are quite far-fetch):

1. Have two threads: one executed theFunc and writes resultingMessage in a variable/file, the other checks this variable/file and updates GUI;
2. Instead of appending lines to resultingMessage, attach some "stream" to GUI element; adding lines to the "stream" would update GUI.

I guess there should be a conventional way to do it.

Environment: CPython 2.7, Win XP, WXPython

Comment: This question has already been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493984/how-to-make-something-like-a-log-box-in-wxpython

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use threads. wxPython provides several thread-safe methods such as wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater and wx.PostEvent. You can combine those with pubsub to send messages too! In your case, I think passing a wx method to wx.CallAfter with whatever text you wish to display would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Driscoll's answer describes what is probably the most commonly used method for doing this.  He has a really good article on his website that goes into much more detail, [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/). He actually has lots of really good articles over there, check them out.

Another way to do this is to set up a timer in your main thread which checks for messages on a queue.  You set up the queue in your **init** method and pass it to a worker thread that runs the long running function.  The worker puts stuff in the queue as needed, and the function tied to the timer event picks the messages/data up in the main thread and updates the GUI, etc.  Here's a short example:

```
#first 4 lines are the bottom of the __init__ method of the main frame
    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.timer.Start(250)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer, self.timer)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.onClose)

def onTimer(self, event):
    '''checks for messages in self.q2 (Queue.Queue set up above)'''
    while not self.q2.empty():
        msg, data = self.q2.get()
        self.update(None, msg, data)

def update(self, event, msg, data):
    '''Runs with data returned in self.q2'''
    self.sb.SetStatusText(msg)
    etc, etc . . .
```

good luck,  Mike